# Key Binds - Middle Mouse Button with Sublime Text 2

Tags: json, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Does anybody know if it's possible to bind the middle mouse button to an action in Sublime Text 2?

I know that some mouse interaction is possible, because you can use the back and forward buttons.

Basically, I was going to use this button to upload a file with the sFTP plugin so it would decrease the amount of buttons I would need to press from 3 to 1.

**Currently, I have:**

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+u"], "command": "sftp_upload_file" }
```

**Ideally it would be something like this:**

```
{ "keys": ["mouse4"], "command": "sftp_upload_file" }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can look at the mouse mappings by opening `Packages/Default/Default (operating system).sublime-mousemap`. You can then change what you want and save it in `Packages/User`.

Comment: I was putting the binds in the keyboard bind file not the mouse file thank you.

Comment: Where can I find the 'Packages/Default/Default (operating system).sublime-mousemap'? Is it a path? Or is it a click path on the menu? I am using Mac and Sublime 3. I don't see anything on the menu that looks similar to this. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out thanks to @MattDMo pointer.

I created a file in

Packages\User\Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap

inside the file I placed

```
[ 
    { "button": "button3", "modifiers": [], "command": "sftp_upload_file" }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sublime portable version (Windows)

Place the mousemap file in SublimeText\Data\Packages\User folder to get it to work, where SublimeText is the portable version directory.