# Is sublime text2 have a shortcut key or other means to jump faster to function code?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I manage java project by Sublime text2.

I know ctrl + R will jump to the definition of function. But when I look through the code, it is not
conveninent to jump by this shortcut key.

Is there some shortcut key or plugin to do this like in eclipse by ctrl + left mouse click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [define mouse & key bindinds in .sublime-mousemap files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965652/key-binds-mouse-buttons-with-sublime-text-2)

In your case, use this binding:

```
{"button": "button1", "count": 1, "modifiers": ["ctrl"],"press_command": "drag_select","command": "goto_definition"}
```

I would suggest to add the `shift` modifier because `CTRL + LEFT CLICK` is used for "multiple selection".

```
{"button": "button1", "count": 1, "modifiers": ["shift","ctrl"],"press_command": "drag_select","command": "goto_definition"}
```

Do no forget to wrap the bindings with `[` and `]` (they are defined as a JSON array of objects)

Regards

Comment: @aantom, have you tried it in a java file? I did as you said and restart the sublime text2. Press ctrl+shift+left click, but it takes no effect at all

Comment: @Harris i have not tested it in Java, but it should work for all functions detected by Sublime Text (i use version 3). You can use `sublime.log_commands(True)` in the console to be sure that the command is used (and to understand the commands that Sublime Text execute). You can also use `sublime.log_input(True)` to debug key strokes.

Comment: @aantom, that's have solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235706/sublime-3-set-key-map-for-function-goto-definition Sorry I've been left for several days

Comment: For Sublime portable version (Windows)

Place the mousemap file in SublimeText\Data\Packages\User folder to get it to work, where SublimeText is the portable version directory.