# Sublime Column Selection with Left Button?

Tags: macos, sublimetext3

According to this [spec](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/editing/editing.html#column-selection), I have to use right mouse button to drag a rectangle for making column selection. This is very inconvenient because I am using a mouse pad and it's hard to do a right click.

Is there a way to fix this binding so that left mouse button can be used instead of right mouse button?

[image]

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965652/key-binds-mouse-buttons-with-sublime-text-2) is useful for you.

Comment: You shouldn't have to change anything. On my Mac (10.8.5, latest ST3 dev build) you can select columns by holding down the Alt/Option key and dragging with the left mouse button (a 3-finger drag, the way I have Apple's Magic Trackpad set up). It also works using an actual mouse.

Comment: I can't do anything with 3-finger drag. Can you explain a bit more about that gesture?